# Problema auto contador de id archivo en c

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con esta función, necesitaría que el id se auto sume cada vez que quiera crear un usuario, la función funciona, el problema es que cuando se cierra el programa y se vuelve a abrir el contador vuelve a 0 y no al valor que tenia antes, alguna ayuda? Gracias.

```
#define maxchar 30
typedef struct{
int id;
char usuario[maxchar];  
char nombre[maxchar];  
char apellido[maxchar];  
char domicilio[maxchar];  
char localidad[maxchar];   
int eliminado; // indica 1 o 0 si el cliente fue eliminado  
}Cliente;

void reg_usuario ()  
{  
int cont=0;  
char control = 's';  
FILE* fichero ;   
Cliente cl; // creo un nuevo cliente de la estructura cliente

fichero=fopen("datos_usuarios","a+b");  
if(fichero==NULL)  
{  
    fichero=fopen("datos_usuarios","a+b");  
}  
  if(fichero!=NULL)  
  {  
    printf ("Menu de Ingreso de usuarios\n");   
    while(cont<30 && control == 's')   
    {    
     printf ("generando ID de usuario automaticamente...\n");    
     fflush(stdin);  
     idaux++;  
     cl.id = idaux;  
     printf("\nIngrese su usuario: ");  
     gets(cl.usuario);  
     printf ("\n Ingrese Nombre: ");  
     fflush(stdin);  
     gets(cl.nombre);  
     printf ("\n Ingrese Apellido: ");   
     fflush(stdin);   
     gets (cl.apellido);   
     printf ("\n Ingrese Domicilio: ");   
     fflush(stdin);   
     gets (cl.domicilio);   
     printf ("\n Ingrese Localidad:");   
     fflush(stdin);   
     gets (cl.localidad);   

     fwrite (&cl, sizeof (cl), 1, fichero);   
     printf ("desea cargar otro usuario? (s/n)");   
     fflush(stdin);  
     scanf("%c",&control);    
     cont ++;    
    }   

    fclose(fichero);    
  }   
}
```

Comment: ¿? En ningún sitio lees ni escribes el contador global (ya sea) `cont` o `idaux`

Comment: El problema esta en que cuando por ej id=1, cuando se crea otro usuario id vuelve a 1 y no a id+1, que seria id 2, nose si se entiende bien la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu *id* se mantenga entre ejecuciones del programa, tienes que guardarlo en algún fichero, base de datos o similar.
Al salir del programa puedes llamar a una función `void guardar(int id)`
que abra un fichero y guarde el id del último usuario registrado.Al volver a iniciar el programa puedes llamar a una función `int leer()` para recuperar el id.
El problema con esto es que si sales abruptamente del programa, este no va a guardar los cambios. Para solucionar esto podrías guardar en el fichero de *id* su valor incrementado cada vez que ejecutes tu función `reg_usuario`.
Para tu caso parece que no es importante, pero esta solución tiene demasiado *overhead* debido a las llamadas de sistema para escribir al archivo. Una optimización interesante podría ser cargar el archivo a memoria.